# FullCalendar with ES6 Build System: "initialView" and "headerToolbar" ignored

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, fullcalendar

I'm moving my script tags based FullCalendar setup to an ES6 build system one and am facing a weird bug that I can't fix.

So I import the FullCalendar class and plugins in my `main-calendar.js` file like this:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import listPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list"
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid"
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid"
```

then, in the same file, I create my `calendar` object like this:

```
    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

        plugins: [listPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin],

        initialView: "list",

        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        }

    })
```

a calendar is rendered BUT:

- `headerToolbar` is always **ignored**. I can add any value to `left`, `center` and `right` but what will be rendered will always be a date on the left and today+prev,next on the right
- `initialView` also always ignored
- the only thing i can change is the initial view by changing the order of the plugins in `plugins` property array. I can switch between `timeGridPlugin` and `dayGridPlugin` and it will change the initial view. `listPlugin` however, if put first in the array doesn't change anything.

It's a Laravel website using Webpack/Laravel mix. My Webpack config:

```
mix.js('resources/js/Calendar/main-calendar.js', 'public/js')
mix.postCss('node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.css', 'public/css/fullcalendar/core.css')
    .postCss('node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css', 'public/css/fullcalendar/daygrid.css')
    .postCss('node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css', 'public/css/fullcalendar/timegrid.css')
    .postCss('node_modules/@fullcalendar/list/main.css', 'public/css/fullcalendar/list.css')
mix.sass('resources/sass/calendar.scss', 'public/css')
```

I'm kindof clueless. I got no errors in my Chrome console and I'll have to rollback to a script tags approach if I can't fix this.

**EDIT**:

in my `package.json` file :

```
"dependencies": {
        ...
        "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^4.4.2",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.2",
        "@fullcalendar/google-calendar": "^4.4.0",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.2",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.4.2",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.2",
        ...
        "fullcalendar": "^5.11.0",
        "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^5.10.2",
        ...

}
```

Comment: Just to check - are you sure it's definitely loading fullCalendar 5? If it's loading an earlier version then those options had different names.

Comment: Seems like you somehow got two different versions (4 and 5) in there, and even different point releases with that, it looks like a mess. You need to sort out your packages so it's all on the same version and point release - e.g. make sure everything targets 5.11.0.

Comment: @ADyson that was it. I upgraded the dependencies and it fixed my issues. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unluckily i still have the same issue and was "fiddeling" around like you mentioned. I used fullcalendar versions 6.1. **Did you finally find a solution?**

Comment: @andreas-supersmart I believe the above comment says that the OP "upgraded the dependencies" in order to find a solution. As I pointed out earlier, they had mixed up different versions of fullcalendar in the various files they were loading into their page. Making everything point to the same version of fullCalendar has resolved their problem. Was there something further you didn't understand from those comments? Thanks

Comment: @Adyson just to let you know, this issue with the `initalView: ` Setting is still not working as expected with V6.1. - I made a workaround after `calendar.render();`

- `calendar.changeView('listYear', '2024-01-01');` 

This does for me what I expect then.

Comment: @andreas-supersmart if you have a specific issue in your code it would be better to post a new question about it with a [mre] so the community can study it fully and hopefully propose a solution to that particular problem. Thanks :-)

Comment: @andreas-supersmart P.S. This simple demo shows that `initialView` does indeed work correctly with 6.1.x: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/NWomEWW

Comment: Thank you so mucch @ADyson - you're right, it works: I had a typo initalView ... an 'i' is missing. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Have a great time!